# Laravel - What is the usage of broadcasting/auth when we can authenticate user in channel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, broadcast

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

What is the usage of `Broadcast::routes()` when `require base_path('routes/channels.php')` is authenticating user with this code `return (int) $user->user_id === (int) $userId;` in `routes/channels.php`?

Answer (score 1):

> Thankfully, Laravel makes it easy to define the routes to respond to
>   channel authorization requests. In the `BroadcastServiceProvider`
>   included with your Laravel application, you will see a call to the
>   `Broadcast::routes` method. This method will register the 
>   `/broadcasting/auth` route to handle authorization requests:

The `Broadcast::routes();` will register the needed authentication base-routes. So when you use Laravel Echo (for example), it will send the authentication request to `/broadcasting/auth`.

> By default, Echo will use the `/broadcasting/auth` endpoint to authorize
>   channel access. However, you may specify your own authorization
>   endpoint by passing the authEndpoint configuration option to your Echo
>   instance:

`window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key',
    authEndpoint: '/custom/endpoint/auth'
});`

Soure: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#defining-authorization-routes

Comment: I had read Laravel doc but what if we don't need authorization? always there is a request to `broadcasting/auth` however I don't want that. I only need authentication. How to disable that?